# I am looking for an HTML5 video player

Tags: video, html

I am currently using JPlayer with a playlist which is nice but does not play well with bootstrap responsive. The player controls and playlist never render.

1. Free
2. Video source can come from anywhere
3. HTML 5 with Flash fallback
4. Playlist
5. Will play nice with bootstrap 3

Edit: Yeah, that is what I said.

Comment: Your question needs some more clarity.  Are you developing a website that uses JPlayer and you want a different player to integrate into your website because of an incompatibility with Bootstrap Responsive?

Answer (score 3):

## Bootstrap has this built in

(see the **[documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed)**)

For local video files:

```
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="yourVid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

For external sources (like YouTube):

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OK5f1xkk3hU?list=RDOK5f1xkk3hU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I know I am really late responding back. I got JPlayer working well enough even though it is not responsive. The bootrap option sucks, it doesn't have controls, can't handle a playlist, etc.  Plus, the docs suck. They are woefully incomplete. If I wanted to write my own player, I wouldn't have asked for other options. But thank you it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 it's a difficult task picking one. I reviewed 6 "best player" lists. Here's the ones that appeared most frequently. I've put them in 3 categories as follows:

Note: 5x means the player appeared in 5 of the 6 lists.

### FREE Standalone Players

- Native HTML5 JavaScript player
- 6x VideoJS (supports HLS)
- 5x Plyr (supports HLS in conjunction with hls.js)
- 2x hls.js (HLS support for native player, other players use it under the hood)

### PAID FOR Fullstack Players

These include a player, encoding, hosting, a web UI based dashboard (for uploading, encoding, configuring, etc) and various APIs (to get a list of videos you have uploaded, to upload via code, etc)

- 5x JW Player
- 4x Flow PLayer
- 4x Kaltura

### Players I am not interested in reviewing

I have not bothered reviewing these because they use jQuery OR do not support HLS streaming OR are Drupal or WordPress only OR are not popular enough OR a combination of these. However, they may suit your needs.

- 5x MediaElement.js (jQuery plugin)
- 5x jPlayer (jQuery plugin)
- 4x Projekktor (Drupal)
- 3x Elite (WordPress only)
- 3x Ultimate (WordPress only)
- 3x Afterglow (deprecated and abandoned)
- 2x Clappr
- 2x Oplayer
- 2x Cloudinary
- 2x Elmedia
- 2x Chameleon
- 2x Video for everybody

### General Notes

If you are using a standalone player and have no budget, you will need to HLS encode your videos yourself. Use ffmpeg to do this. You will also need to host them somewhere.

### Reviews

I spent one week reviewing these players and performance testing them. Here's the outcome:

### FREE Standalone Players

- Native HTML5 JavaScript player - Does not support HLS streaming (except in Safari) resulting in slow seek times. My advice, if you need performance, do not use until it supports HLS. Current time updates are slow.
- VideoJS - One of the most performant standalone players. Horrible docs but a big community helps. Supports HLS out the box. Definitely worth considering. Current time updates are fast (but not sure if they are accurate, since under the hood it relies on the slow time updates from the native player).
- Plyr - I reviewed this due to their awesome demo. However, it did not perform as well as VideoJS therefore I stopped further integrations. However, if you need Vimeo and YouTube support you probably want this one. For HLS, you need to use this in conjunction with hls.js. Current time updates are better than native but not as fast as Video.js
- hls.js - A lot of big name video players use this (or used to use it) under the hood. You can use this in conjunction with the native player. It allows the native player to use HLS. A good solid library. Performance was not bad. Definitely worth considering. Current time updates are better than native but not as fast as Video.js

### Fullstack Players

- JW Player - The big boy of the industry. YouTube was initially built on this. Performs well. Docs are sometimes hard to work with due to the sheer volume. Using their embedded player, their current time updates are slower than native. Have not tried their JavaScript player (which requires an Enterprise account). 30 day free trial available. Definitely worth considering if you got cash.
- Flow Player - The new kid on the block. Uses the native player JavaScript API but extends it, which is nice as it means you are using familiar commands. Docs are very good and plugins are super simple to integrate with. However, whilst a good number of options are available, JW Player offers more. Performance is very similar to JW Player. Current time updates are pretty fast (much better than JW Player). Definitely worth considering if you got cash. 14 day free trial available.
- Kaltura - Sad to say but don't waste your time looking at this. The player is not responsive (fixed width only). Seeking does not update the current time until the seek is completed. The docs are OK but hard work. Integration is clunky. The dashboard is a bit all over the place. If you can live with all the above then performance is good. 2 month free trial.

Just to advise I am NOT affiliated with any of the above players or their companies. All the best. Thank J-E--S-U-S not me :D