# HTML5 video player that is cross-platform

Tags: video, html

I'm trying to play .mp4 on my website. There are a few plugins out there but too many to decide from. What does everyone use for their site and the pros and cons? I need something that supports all browsers and mobile devices and all OS that support HTML5 video.

Looking for something self-hosted.

I don't know which one to go with:

- mediaelements.js
- sublime video now dead
- projekttor
- jplayer
- video.js

What do you use or recommend for your site?

Comment: What CMS are you using, if any? What are your requirements in a video player? And what is wrong with the default video player invoked by the `<video>` tag?

Comment: this help? https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20174/i-am-looking-for-an-html5-video-player/80670#80670

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out the [LEADTOOLS Media Server SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/media-streaming-server). This product includes a web page that determines which player would be the best player to use for that device, whether it be a tablet, phone, or PC. The media server is designed to use MP4 files as input and stream them out to any device, and it is self-hosted. No integration with IIS, Apache, etc.

You can check it out live from the website [here](http://demo.leadtools.com/mediastreaming/player.html).

Disclaimer: I am an employee of the company that wrote this library.