# HTML5 video player replacemenet for JWplayer m3u8 capability

Tags: video, html

I found that Jwplayer can play a single large movie from small parts listed in a m3u8 playlist but unfortunately it seems that it supports only ts files and so I need to convert my files into ts. Is there another replacement for JwPlayer which I can split large MP4 into small mp4 files (Not ts) and play them in a row into a HTML player? Does native video players support such option?

Comment: this help? https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20174/i-am-looking-for-an-html5-video-player/80670#80670

Comment: Why would you like to split the files in the first place? Any modern HTML5 player can play portions from and seek in large files without first downloading it. (Well, depending on the sever supporting ranged respones, but that should not be a problem nowadays)

Comment: My reason is to prevent downloading by a single url @Marcel Is there any other replacement for this purpose?